# NotSerializableException with BasicDataSource in JNDI

Tags: datasource, jndi, notserializableexception, initial-context

I am setting up a standalone JNDI and loading a Datasource to the JNDI.
DataSource I use is: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

The JNDI is set up as follows

```
        String detectorHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        System.out.println("detectorHost: " + detectorHost);
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        final NamingBeanImpl namingInfo = new NamingBeanImpl();
        namingInfo.start();

        final Main JNDIServer = new Main();

        JNDIServer.setNamingInfo( namingInfo );
        JNDIServer.setPort( 5400 );
        JNDIServer.setBindAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        JNDIServer.start();

        final Hashtable _properties = new Hashtable();
        _properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        _properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,            "jnp://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + ":5400");

        final Context _context = new InitialContext(_properties);
        _context.createSubcontext("jdbc");
        String JNDI_PATH = "jdbc" + "/" + "mydbname";
        _context.bind(JNDI_PATH, getDataSource());
```

I get the following exception

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is     java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:677)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:611)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.lombardrisk.reform.integration.ReformIntegration.createJNDIServer(ReformIntegration.java:93)
    at     com.lombardrisk.reform.integration.ReformIntegration.main(ReformIntegration.java:44)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.MarshalledValuePair.<init>(MarshalledValuePair.java:65)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.createMarshalledValuePair(NamingContext.java:1425)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:640)
```

I don't quite follow why I am getting a NotSerializableException exception, this is a local JNDI in the same JVM and not a remote JNDI. Not sure why this occurs.

Can some one advise what is wrong here.

regards
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception was misleading. The exception became clear after adding the following to the JVM startup

-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true

It appears I was not using the correct libraries.
I have explained the full problem and solution here in this link.
https://community.jboss.org/thread/241498

```
//Code to start a JNDI Server and a test client for the JNDI Context

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jnp.server.Main;
import org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl;

//Snippet of the code

    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "localhost");
    System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    final NamingBeanImpl namingInfo = new NamingBeanImpl();            
    namingInfo.start();

    final Main jndiServer = new Main();


    jndiServer.setNamingInfo(namingInfo);
    jndiServer.setPort(1099);
    jndiServer.setBindAddress("localhost");
    jndiServer.setRmiPort(1098);
    jndiServer.setRmiBindAddress("localhost");
    jndiServer.start();   
    final Hashtable<String, String> _properties = new Hashtable<String, String> ();
    _properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
    _properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,            "jnp://" + "localhost" + ":1099");
    final Context _context = new InitialContext(_properties);
    _context.createSubcontext("jdbc");
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    System.out.println("jdbcTemplate:  " + jdbcTemplate.getClass());
    System.out.println("getDataSource(): " + getDataSource().getClass());
    _context.bind("/jdbc/reformDS", getDataSource());

//JNDI started


//Test the JNDI context
// There are 2 ways to test - 
// Option 1: create a HashTable and pass the properties to the InitialContext constructor
    final Hashtable<String, String> _properties = new Hashtable<String, String> ();
    _properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
    _properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,            "jnp://" + "localhost" + ":1099");

final Context _context = new InitialContext(_properties);
Object obj = _context.lookup("/jdbc/reformDS");
if (null != obj) {
System.out.println("OBJ: " + obj.getClass());
           org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource ds = (org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource)obj;
           JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2 = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
           String sql = String.format("update MESSAGE_LOG set PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = 123456 where ID =42395 ");      
           int update = jdbcTemplate2.update(sql);
           System.out.println("Update*****************: " + update);
           }


// Option 2: Set the System.properties and call the InitialContext 
System.getProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,            "jnp://" + "localhost" + ":1099");
final Context _context = new InitialContext();
Object obj = _context.lookup("/jdbc/reformDS");
if (null != obj) {
System.out.println("OBJ: " + obj.getClass());
           org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource ds = (org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource)obj;
           JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2 = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
           String sql = String.format("update MESSAGE_LOG set PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = 123456 where ID =42395 ");      
           int update = jdbcTemplate2.update(sql);
           System.out.println("Update*****************: " + update);
           }
```